# How to select alternative subpaths in xpath

Tags: xpath

This works:

```
(//someparentpath/h3 | //someparentpath/ul/li/div)/somechildpath
```

This does not :( Why?

```
//someparentpath/(h3 | ul/li/div)/somechildpath
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

XPath 1.0's grammar does not allow alternations in axis steps, see the [specifications for node sets](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-sets) or try the [XPath 1.0 Grammar Test Page](http://www.w3.org/2013/01/qt-applets/xpath1/). Your first query is allowed by the grammar, the second is no valid XPath 1.0.

If you've got any chance, **switch to an XPath 2.0** implementation which offers *much more* possibilities in querying XML. Both of your queries are valid XPath 2.0 statements.

In **XPath 1.0**, you will have to either:

- Completely write out the path two times and use the union of those:

  ```
  //someparentpath/h3/somechildpath | //someparentpath/ul/li/div/somechildpath
  ```

  or the allowed query with common axis steps *in the end*, which is at least a little bit less repeating:

  ```
  (//someparentpath/h3 | //someparentpath/ul/li/div)/somechildpath
  ```
- Use some `descending-or-self`-hack with predicates like proposed by harpo and JLRishe, but they have both in common that you might match more elements than you want to.

Answer (score 4):

I think the closest you can get is the following:

```
//someparentpath//*[self::h3 or self::div[parent::li/parent::ul]]/somechildpath
```

However, as harpo already mentioned, the `//` prevents them from being exactly equivalent and I don't think there is a way around that in a single expression. Note that if you are working in XSLT, you can use multiple variable assignments to achieve what you are trying to do and avoid some portion of the redundancy:

```
<xsl:variable name="ppath" select="//someparentpath" />
<xsl:variable name="children" select="($ppath/h3 | $ppath/ul/div/li)/somechildpath" />
```

Note that the hypothetical expression you described:

```
//someparentpath/(h3 | ul/li/div)/somechildpath
```

***is*** allowed in XPath 2.0. It's simply not allowed in XPath 1.0 because 1.0 does not allow you to have expressions partway through a path.

Answer (score 2):

Good question, I'm interested in the "why" myself.

As a practical matter, though, you can rewrite this

```
//someparentpath/(h3 | ul/li/div)/somechildpath
```

as this (not quite equivalent)

```
//someparentpath//*[self::h3 or self::ul/li/div]/somechildpath
```

Which is not too much worse.

But yeah, I've been frustrated by that.

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me the same as //someparentpath/h3/somechildpath | //someparentpath/ul/somechildpath

Comment: @Marina, my mistake, please see edit.  This isn't exactly equivalent to what you're asking for, but may be close enough.  The difference is that it can include `h3`'s (as well as `ul/li/div`'s) that are not direct children of `someparentpath`.  For that, I'm afraid you'd need the redundant expression.